# could not work ssl connection properly when keystore file changed dynamically through web application

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, keytool

am trying to change the truststore path dynamically using java web application.

am developing struts application and login is based on ldap through secure socket layer (ssl) connection.

To connect with ssl i have created .cer file using java keytool option.

Now i able to connect with ldap and i can retieve user information from ldap.

when i change the ssl certificate(invalid certificate for testing) dynamically it could not give any exceptions. but it works when i restart the tomcat
server.

following is the code that i am trying

```
try{
        java.io.InputStream in = new java.io.FileInputStream("C:\\test.cer");
        java.security.cert.Certificate c = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(in);
        java.security.KeyStore ks = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(null); 
        if (!ks.containsAlias("alias ldap")) { 
            ks.setCertificateEntry("alias ldap", c);
        }
        java.io.OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream("C:\\ldap.jks");
        char[] kspass = "changeit".toCharArray();
        ks.store(out, kspass);
        out.close();
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\ldap.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");    
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

is there any mistake that i made with the code?
does any new code that i need to put to connect dynamically?

Note : 
    instead of c:\ldap.jks file i gave invalid file dynamically. it does not give any exception.

**Edited (checked with custom TrustManager) :**

i also implemented TrustManager and ssl context is initialized with custom trust manager.
but i am not able to get the expected behaviour

could u please help me. the code that i tried is

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class TestDynamicSSLCert {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws NamingException,IOException {
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream (System.in);
        String yes = "yes";

        String certpath = "C:\\cert.cer";
        String ldappath1 = "C:\\ldap.jks";
        String ldappath2 = "C:\\ldap.jks";    // setting valid key store path    

        while("yes".equalsIgnoreCase(yes.trim())){            
            System.out.println(" ldappath2 : "+ldappath2);
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"uid=admin,ou=system");
            env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "secret");
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldaps://172.16.12.4:636/ou=system");
            try {

                java.io.InputStream in = new java.io.FileInputStream(certpath);
                java.security.cert.Certificate c = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(in);
                java.security.KeyStore ks = java.security.KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                ks.load(null);
                if (!ks.containsAlias("alias ldap")) {
                    ks.setCertificateEntry("alias ldap", c);
                }
                java.io.OutputStream out = new java.io.FileOutputStream(ldappath1);
                char[] kspass = "changeit".toCharArray();
                ks.store(out, kspass);
                out.close();
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", ldappath2);
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "changeit");              
                // Custorm trust manager 
                MyX509TrustManager reload = new MyX509TrustManager(ldappath2,c);
                TrustManager[] tms = new TrustManager[] { reload };
                javax.net.ssl.SSLContext sslCtx = javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
                sslCtx.init(null, tms, null);  
                // Custom trust manager
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DirContext ctx = new InitialDirContext(env);
            NamingEnumeration enm = ctx.list("");
            while (enm.hasMore()) {
                System.out.println(enm.next());
            }                    
            ctx.close();
            System.out.println(" Go again by yes/no :");
            yes = din.readLine();
            ldappath2 = "C:\\invalidldap.jks"; // setting invalid keystore path

        }
    }
}

class MyX509TrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

    private final String trustStorePath;
    private X509TrustManager trustManager;
    private List<Certificate> tempCertList = new ArrayList<Certificate>();

    public MyX509TrustManager(String tspath,Certificate cert)throws Exception{
        this.trustStorePath = tspath;        
        tempCertList.add(cert);
        reloadTrustManager();
    }

    public MyX509TrustManager(String tspath)
            throws Exception {
        this.trustStorePath = tspath;
        reloadTrustManager();
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
        trustManager.checkClientTrusted(chain, authType);
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
            String authType) throws CertificateException {
        try {
            trustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        } catch (CertificateException cx) {
            addServerCertAndReload(chain[0], true);
            trustManager.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        X509Certificate[] issuers = trustManager.getAcceptedIssuers();
        return issuers;
    }

    private void reloadTrustManager() throws Exception {

        // load keystore from specified cert store (or default)
        KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(trustStorePath);
        try {
            ts.load(in, null);
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }

        // add all temporary certs to KeyStore (ts)
        for (Certificate cert : tempCertList) {         
            ts.setCertificateEntry(UUID.randomUUID().toString(), cert);
        }

        // initialize a new TMF with the ts we just loaded
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ts);

        // acquire X509 trust manager from factory
        TrustManager tms[] = tmf.getTrustManagers();

        for (int i = 0; i < tms.length; i++) {
            if (tms[i] instanceof X509TrustManager) {                
                trustManager = (X509TrustManager) tms[i];
                return;
            }
        }

        throw new NoSuchAlgorithmException("No X509TrustManager in TrustManagerFactory");
    }

    private void addServerCertAndReload(Certificate cert,
            boolean permanent) {
        try {
            if (permanent) {
                // import the cert into file trust store
                // Google "java keytool source" or just ...
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("keytool -importcert ...");
            } else {
                tempCertList.add(cert);
            }
            reloadTrustManager();
        } catch (Exception ex) { /* ... */ }
    }
}
```

**Expected Behaviour :**

ldap connection should be successfull with valid  keystore file (during first loop ).
if user give yes then invalid keystore is assigned and need to produce exception and should not connect to ldap

**Actual Behaviour:**

for both valid keystore file i able to retrieve information from ldap.

**Note :**

if i set String ldappath2 = "C:\invalidldap.jks"; at begining, it gives exception.

**Why am doing this ?**

@EJP, because, i need to develope module which is based on ldap authentication securely. module should support multiple ldap servers. ldap settings can be inserted from the UI (webpage that has the ui to get the details like ldaphost, port, basedn, and ssl certificate) and this details should go to database. at the same time certificate also present in database. work for module is just retrieve the users from ldap and store it to another table. so if we change the new ldap server setting with new certificate means, System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore","truststorepath") will fail. are you okay with my explanation?

Comment: No I'm not OK with it. Why use SSL if you don't want it to be secure? That's the purpose of the certificate, the truststore, etc. SSL without proper peer authentication is not secure. Period. See RFC 2246 if you don't believe it here.

Comment: Are you telling, the above module could not implemented with secure connection? How it should be implemented ?

Comment: The connection cannot be secure unless the peer is authenticated. The peer cannot be authenticated unless you already have a reason to trust his identity that you didn't receive over the connection you are trying to authenticate. It has to be offline.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct. You have to restart Tomcat when you change the keystore or truststore. You don't need to write code to load client certificates, you just need to make sure you are dealing with servers whose certificates are signed by a CA that you trust. Adding new certificates at runtime is radically insecure.

Comment: For more advanced use, there could be a custom `TrustManager` that refreshes its trust anchors regularly, but you're right, adding certificates at run time shouldn't be done in this case. It doesn't seem necessary either, since this should be done when setting the LDAP server connection, once and for all.

Comment: @Bruno, does custom TrustManager implementation supports dynamic certificate changes ?

Comment: @Mohan, if you implement it to do so, it could. However, there doesn't seem to be any point in your case: you're clearly loading the cert from a file at the start to save it into your keystore. You could do that with `keytool`, no need for dynamic loading here.

Comment: @Bruno, yes. this is test code that i put. but during the runtime i will give dynamic values instead of "C:\\ldap.jks" using some variables from the web page. so that am testing this one.

Comment: @Mohan Why? You need to understand that receiving certificates to trust via the channel that they authenticate is still insecure. Trusted certificates need to be received offline.

Comment: @Mohan, this trust manager you've put in your edited question is completely useless. Essentially, if you don't trust the cert already, you're adding it to the trusted list blindly. You might as well disable any trust verification, which is a *bad idea*.

Comment: @Bruno and EJP, okay. i have a question. if i want to change the truststore property dynamically means what i need to do ? or is it possible to change the truststore property dynamically ?

Comment: @Mohan I also have a question, and I have already asked it. Why?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to connect ldap securely with out using above
>   steps?

Yes, but why do you think you need to know?

> Does the application (tomcat or single java file) should be restarted
>   whenever trustStore property is updated ?

Yes.

Comment: till now, i know only, two way to set trust store property . if i know other ways means, it will easy to check out and implement it to my project. so, what are the other way?